# Vertical align inner div at percentage of height of outer div

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I have a div of unknown height in a div of 100% height. I want the inner div to vertically align at 30% from the bottom of the outer div.

In the following working example, using `middle` aligns the inner div in the vertical middle of the outer div. But using `30%` **pushes the inner div halfway outside the browser window!**

**Screenshot of "vertical-align: middle":**

[image]

**Screenshot of "vertical-align: 30%":**

[image]

Why? And how can I get the inner div to where the arrow points?

*The solution must not define a height for the inner div!*

**Sampe code:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        /* reset */
        html, body {
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
        }
        html, body, #wrapper {
            height: 100%;
        }
        #wrapper {
            left: 0;
            position: fixed;
            text-align: center;
            top: 0;
            width: 100%;
        }
        #wrapper:before {
            content: "";
            display: inline-block;
            height: 100%;
            margin-right: 0;
            vertical-align: middle; // or 30%  <= change position here
            width: 1px;
        }
        #header {
            display: inline-block;
            position: relative;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <header id="header">
            <h1>Text</h1>
            <p>More text</p>
        </header>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    #wrapper:before {
        content: "";
        display: inline-block;
        height: 70%;
        margin-right: 0;
        width: 1px;
    }
```